# A property for an ODE

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

$2\leq n\in\mathbb{N}$. I have no idea how to show that there is a unique solution $y\in C^1([0,T))$ of the ODE

\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{cases}
y'(t)=(1+y(t)^2)\left(1-\dfrac{n-1}{t}y(t)\right)\ \ \ &(t>0)\\
y(0)=0
\end{cases}
\end{eqnarray} when $T>0$ is sufficiently small. (In fact the solution exists in $C^1([0,\infty))$. )Please help me whenever you can show the short-time existence. Thank you.

Since this ODE doesn't have the Lipschitz condition and $F(t,y):=(1+y^2)\left(1-\dfrac{n-1}{t}y\right)$ is not bounded around the point $(t,y)=(0,0)$, there is no general method to justify the unique existence in my knowledge.

Comment: Just one little observation: if solution exists and satisfies $y(0) = 0$, it also satisfies a non-trivial condition on $y'(0)$ (you can find it by passing to the limit $t \rightarrow 0$).

Comment: My analysis is rusty, but I think it suffices to show that if the RHS is $\in C^{1}$, then the solution exists.

Comment: @DemetriP: Of course. The problem here is exactly the singularity at $t=0$.

Comment: Have you managed to solve this problem in the end? I tried but I couldn't, so I gave up. But now I am very curious.

Answer (score 0):

The right side is $C^1$ in $y$ (and also in $t$). It follows that the right side is locally Lipschitz continuous in $y$, so that the assumption of Picard-Lindelöf are satisfied and the existence of a unique local solution follows.

The argument for $C^1$ functions on the right side of the ODE is also packaged as a theorem of Cauchy(-Lagrange?).

---

Observation: Substituting $y=\tan(u)$, $v=t^{n-1}\sin(u)=t^{n-1}y/\sqrt{1+y^2}$, the equation compresses to $v'=\pm\sqrt{t^{2n-2}-v^2}$

Comment: But there is a singularity at $t=0$. Did you take this into account?

Comment: No, of course not. Thanks, that invalidates this argument and renders the initial condition redundant. Without $y(0)=0$ there would be no solution.